# Teams custom favicon missing from inbox/achievements

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog, stack-overflow-for-teams

When I open my inbox from the teams actual page, it comes up with the correct icons:

[image]

But while opening it on any other SE site it doesn't show any Icon

[image]

Same happens with the Achievements Dropdown